# Child does not update when generated via array react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've made a simple react app where i am generated child components via an array that is inside my state:

School.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

export default class School extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      persons: [
        {id: 0, name: "person0"},
        {id: 1, name: "person1"},
        {id: 2, name: "person2"},
        {id: 3, name: "person3"},
        {id: 4, name: "person4"},
        {id: 5, name: "person5"},
        {id: 6, name: "person6"},
        {id: 7, name: "person7"},
        {id: 8, name: "person8"},
        {id: 9, name: "person9"}
      ]
    };

    this.personList = this.state.persons.map((p) =>
      <Person key={p.id} info={p} updateState={this.updateState.bind(this)} />
    );
  }

  updateState(){
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        {id: 0, name: "person000000000"},
        {id: 1, name: "person100000000"},
        {id: 2, name: "person200000000"},
        {id: 3, name: "person300000000"},
        {id: 4, name: "person400000000"},
        {id: 5, name: "person500000000"},
        {id: 6, name: "person600000000"},
        {id: 7, name: "person700000000"},
        {id: 8, name: "person800000000"},
        {id: 9, name: "person900000000"}
      ]
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>All my persons:</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.personList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Person.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Person extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("updated");
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <p onClick={this.props.updateState}>I'm {this.props.info.name} and my id is {this.props.info.id}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

My childs are rendered, but when i update the state via onClick on one of my childs, the state is updated (you can check it when you console.log in 'updateState' method in School), but my childs are not rerendered.

How does this come and why? Can you create children like this (via array in state)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason is**, you are storing the `UI items` in global variable, and that is not getting updated, because `constructor` gets called only once during the initial `rendering`. Instead of that use that `map` inside `render` method, it will work, and remove the `map` from `constructor` also.

Like this:

```
CreateList(){
   return this.state.persons.map((p) =>
      <Person key={p.id} info={p} updateState={this.updateState.bind(this)} />
    );
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>All my persons:</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.CreateList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Why it will work**: On `setState` `React` will trigger the `re-rendering` and it will create the new `ui-items` based on updated `state` value.